# Angularjs $componentController TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'controller.name')

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to do do unit testing for Angular 1.5.6 for components with Jasmine. However, I keep receiving the error below and not sure why.

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'controller.name')

component :

```
function MainViewerCtrl() {
    this.$onInit = function(){
        console.log('Component main viewer initialized!');
    };
    this.name = 'Main Component!';
}

angular.module('ks').component('mainViewer', {
    bindings: {
        name : '@'
    },
    controller : MainViewerCtrl,
    templateUrl: "mainViewer.html"
});
```

spec :

```
describe('Component : mainViewer', function(){

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ks'));

  describe('with $componentController', function () {

    var controller, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $componentController){

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $componentController('mainViewer',
                                         {$scope:scope},
                                         {name: 'Main Component!'} );
    }));

    it('should have my binding bound', function() {

        expect(controller.name).toBeDefined();
        expect(controller.name).toBe('Main Component!');
    });
});
```

});

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Did You try/saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462102)?

I had similar problem where *$componentController* were undefined, after all it turned out i had module dependencies in my app (ui-router, ngResource) that was not added into files in karma config. As they were not loaded inject just did not work properly.

Comment: How did you find out which dependencies were missing? I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984613/how-to-test-angular-1-6-component-with-injected-service

Answer (score 1):

Try to run Karma without PhantomJS, but rather on Chrome or Firefox. I've found that using `angular.mock.inject` in combination with PhantomJS leads to (for me) undefined parameters in the `inject` function and ultimately (and even when the logic of my unit test did not require it) to fail my tests. Removing PhantomJS from the configured browsers allowed me to at least continue my testing, albeit not knowing what the root cause was.

Answer (score -1):

You have to inject `_$componentController_` instead of `$componentController`.
Check last test example on page https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

```
var $componentController;
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$componentController_){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
    controller = $componentController('mainViewer',
                                     {$scope:scope},
                                     {name: 'Main Component!'} );
}));
```

Comment: you do not have to do this...the underscores in `_$componentController_` are a convention so that you can inject it and not use up the variable name `$componentController`. I'm getting $componentController is undefined myself.