# How to test Angular 1.6 component with injected service?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-components, angularjs-1.6

I want to test my Angular component which is syntactically based on [John Papa's styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide):

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('MyModule')
    .component('MyCmpnt', MyCmpnt())
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCmpnt() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'myPath/myTemplate.html',
        bindings: {
            foo: '=',
            bar: '<'
        },
        controller: 'MyCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
}

MyCtrl.$inject = ['MyService'];

function MyCtrl (MyService) {
    // controller logic
}
```

As you can see I want to *inject* `MyService` into the controller and **spy** in a function on that very *service*.

My test code:

```
'use strict';

describe('component: MyCmpnt', function () {

    var $componentController,
        MyService;

    beforeEach(module('MyModule'));

    beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('MyService', MyService);

        spyOn(MyService, 'serviceFunc').and.callThrough();
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$componentController_) {
        $componentController = _$componentController_;
    }));


    it('should initiate the component and define bindings', function () {

        var bindings = {
            foo: 'baz',
            bar: []
        };

        var ctrl = $componentController('MyCmpnt', null, bindings);

        expect(ctrl.foo).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

However, this setup lets me run into the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$componentController('MyModule', null, bindings)')

Comment: There is no 'MyModule' component...

Comment: @estus: `MyModule` is a module, consisting of a component `MyCmpnt` and the corresponding controller `MyCtrl`. What do you mean though?

Comment: You're doing `$componentController('MyModule'...`, and there is no MyModule component. This exactly what error message says. It is MyCmpnt. Not MyModule.

Comment: You're right thanks, it was a typeing mistake but it the above error remains since `$componentController` is undefined. That means the injection has not even been executed.

Comment: This doesn't add up. `is not a constructor` means not just something went undefined but a constructor went undefined. Angular uses constructors only for controllers and `service` services . I suggest to double check if you've corrected this in the spec you're running, because I see no other reasonable explanation for this error from the code above.  If the problem persists, consider providing a plunk/fiddle that can replicate this error. Btw, you have `MyService` variable undefined in the code above (`spyOn(MyService...` would throw), this means that posted code differs from real code.

Comment: Apparently, `spyOn(MyService, 'serviceFunc').and.callThrough();` throws an error when being initiated within the same `beforeEach()` function like `$provide`. Moreover, this error seems getting swallowed by the PhantomJS reporter. Moving the spy to the `beforeEach(inject(function (_$componentController_) {}));` function works. Thanks for your effort @estus, you can post this as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure. Error swallowing is the most common problem with Karma tests I've met, but it doesn't seem like it was the case, because if there is a bootstrap error, this will result in `$componentController` being undefined (and `undefined is not a constructor` error means that it was defined), Any way, I would suggest to switch to Chrome if you have suspicions that the errors are suppressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above has `$componentController('MyModule'...`, and there is no `MyModule` component.

`MyService` variable is undefined when `spyOn(MyService...` is called. This will throw an error prevent the application from being bootstrapped correctly.

If testing rig uses PhantomJS, this may lead to error suppression in `beforeEach` blocks, for correct error reporting Chrome Karma launcher is recommended.

If the problem is that `MyService` is undefined at the point where mocked service is defined, it can be defined in-place as a stub:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('MyService', {
      serviceFunc: jasmine.createSpy().and.callThrough()
    });
}));
```